# getting "System.OutOfMemoryException" while declaring multidimensional array

Tags: vb.net

I have a requirement where i need to copy data from data table to multidimensional array but when i am  declare multidimensional array i am getting Memory error. please suggest solution.

```
Dim my_array(number, number, number, number, number, number, number, number, number, number, number) As String
```

where number is number of Rows coming from database i.e `SELECT COUNT(COL.NAME) FROM TABLE_NAME`.

if i use:

```
Dim my_array(number, number, number, number, number, number, number, number, number) As String
```

there is no error.

Comment: You should probably use a `Datatable` instead of a multi dimensional array. As for your problem: Single objects in .NET < 4.5 are limited to 2 GB in size. You seem to have a lot of data to handle, so it may exceed this limit. Be more specific: What is your data, what are you trying to achieve? If you can use .NET 4.5 refer to this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Some simple math will explain the issue. If you make the bad assumption that each array element will only consume 1byte of memory (it won't), and you only have 10 rows in your table the amount of memory required for my_array that works is 10^9 bytes = 1GB of memory. For the one that doesn't work you would need 10^12 bytes = 1000GB

Comment: @JonathanHouston I don't get your math. If he has 11 arrays with 10 rows each you will get `11*10=110 elements * 1 Byte = 110 Bytes` (not that your general idea of too much data in one array isn't plausible).

Comment: @Jens a 3 dimensional array that is 10x10x10 will allows for referencing 10^3 unique array elements if i'm remembering correctly so higher dimension arrays should maintain that relation ship. For your example he would be defining and array of (11,10) which is only 2 dimensional. See [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2de1t93%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for information on multi-dimensional arrays

Comment: Oh you're right. My bad. I was thinking about jagged arrays (which he probably wants given a database table).

Comment: whats with the tag spam?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have skipped [this section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt(v=vs.90).aspx) when reading the docs. If I understand you correctly you're trying to create a `x,y` array. Instead of using jagged arrays I suggest you use a multidimensional array.

Here's an example where I create 10 rows and 3 columns:

```
Dim tableArray As String(,) = New String(10, 3) {}

For rowIndex As Integer = 0 To 9 '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 = 10 rows
    For columnIndex As Integer = 0 To 2 '0,1,2 = 3 columns
        tableArray(rowIndex, columnIndex) = String.Format("Row={0}, Column={1}", rowIndex, columnIndex)
    Next
Next
```

However, a better way would be to simply [copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) the data table.

```
Dim table2 As DataTable = table1.Copy()
```

If you need to filter the table then use the default [data view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx) of the table:

```
table1.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Name LIKE '*Smith*'"
Dim table2 As DataTable = table1.DefaultView.ToTable()
```

Or create a new data view:

```
Dim view As New DataView(table1)
view.RowFilter = "Name LIKE '*Smith*'"
Dim table2 As DataTable = view.ToTable()
```